# HtmlHelper Extension - User Conrol

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-controls, html-helper

I have a custom user control called ErrorNotificationBox.  To place that on my page I do the old...

```
<%@ Register Src="~/PathTo/ErrorNotificationBox.ascx" TagName="ErrorNotificationBox" TagPrefix="uc" %>

<uc:ErrorNotificationBox Runat="server" id="myEnb" Caption="My Test Caption" />
```

Is it possible to extend HtmlHelper to include my user control?  I.e...

```
<%= Html.ErrorNotificationBox("My Test Caption")%>
```

Many thanks for any help.

ETFairfax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the methods in html helper are Extension methods.  You can easily add your own.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string ErrorNotificationBox(this HtmlHelper helper, string caption)
    {
        //generate and return the html for your error box here. 
        // loading and returning an instance of a user control (.ascx) 
        // as a string is difficult.  You may find it easier to 
        // create the html with a string builder.
    }
}
```